# Implement security logic to limit access to data based on configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement logic to restrict download access:

```
   const userPermittedFutures = {};
    
    app.get('/futures', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
        const query = {
            name: 'fetch-futures-portfolios',
            text: 'SELECT ' +
                'future.instrument.symbol ' +
                .......
                'WHERE future.exchange.name = $1',
            values: ['Futures'],
        };
        const futuresPortfolios = await pgClient.query(query).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Failed to select futures portfolios: " + err.message);
            res.status(503).send({
                status: 'fail',
                message: err.message
            });
            return;
        });
    
        let allowedFuturesAssetsForUser = futuresPortfolios.rows;
        let currentUser = initializePassport.getCurrentUser();
        let traderId = traderIdMnemonicMapping[currentUser]
    
        if (!getPermittedFuturesAssets[traderId]) {
            console.log("Couldn't find Futures contracts for " + currentUser)
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Specific Futures contracts are set for user " + currentUser);
            allowedFuturesAssetsForUser = Object.keys(getPermittedFuturesAssets[traderId]);
        }
    
        res.status(200).send(allowedFuturesAssetsForUser);
    
    });
    
    const getPermittedFuturesAssets = (traderId) => {
        if (!pgClient) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                getPermittedFuturesAssets()
            }, 1000);
            return;
        }
        const query = {
            name: 'fetch-futures-assets-permissions',
            text: 'SELECT trader_id, pair, pair_limit ' +
                'FROM common.accounts_pairs_permits app ' +
                'WHERE exists(SELECT * FROM future.instrument ap WHERE ap.symbol = app.pair) AND trader_id = $1',
            values: [traderId],
        };
        pgClient.query(query, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Can't get account permitted futures permits. Retrying in a second...");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getPermittedFuturesAssets();
                }, 1000);
                return;
            }
            for (let row of res.rows) {
                addUserFuturesConstraints(row.trader_id, row.pair, row.pair_limit);
            }
        });
    }
    
    function addUserFuturesConstraints(trading_id, futuresAsset, limit) {
        if (!userPermittedFutures[trading_id]) {
            let user_permitted_limits = {}
            user_permitted_limits[futuresAsset] = createUserFuturesAssetsConstraints(limit);
            userPermittedFutures[trading_id] = user_permitted_limits;
        } else {
            userPermittedFutures[trading_id][futuresAsset] = createUserFuturesAssetsConstraints(limit);
        }
    }
    
    function isUserAbleToTradeFutures(req, res, next) {
        if (adminUsers[req.user.username]) { // admin users can trade with all pairs without limits
            return next();
        }
        if (!isFuturesAssetAllowedForUser(req.user.username, req.body.selectedPair)) {
            return res.status(503).send({status: "Failed to execute because Futures Asset is not allowed for user."});
        }
        if (isUserFuturesLimitReached(req.user.username, req.body.amount, req.body.selectedPair)) {
            return res.status(503).send({status: "Failed to execute because the order exceeds the user's trading limit for Futures Asset."});
        }
        return next();
    }
    
    function isFuturesAssetAllowedForUser(username, selectedFutureAsset) {
        let traderId = traderIdMnemonicMapping[username];
        if (!userPermittedFutures[traderId]) {
            return false;
        }
        for (let futureAsset of Object.entries(userPermittedFutures[traderId])) {
            if (futureAsset[0] === selectedFutureAsset) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    function isUserFuturesLimitReached(username, amount, selectedFuturesAsset) {
        let traderId = traderIdMnemonicMapping[username]
        if (!userPermittedFutures[traderId][selectedFuturesAsset]) { // if limit is undefined then it is unlimited.
            return false;
        }
        return parseFloat(amount) > userPermittedFutures[traderId][selectedFuturesAsset].pairQuantityLimit;
    }
    
    function createUserFuturesAssetsConstraints(pairQuantityLimit) {
        return {
            pairQuantityLimit: parseFloat(pairQuantityLimit),
            splitConstraints: [],
        }
    }
```

But I'm stuck how to implement `createUserFuturesAssetsConstraints`.
When user tries to access endpoint and make request see should be limited to an asset for example `asset1` based on the username.

How I can implement the logic so that user can can access only a defined list of items based on his username?

Comment: what's props? it is not shown in your code. I will assume that are the passed props to that component, then, what are you passing there? Apparently that object does not have an `onMessageNotificationWebsocket` method

Comment: You need to check that the object you are passing has that function, because apparently it does not contain it, or you are not passing it or it is not a function (can be a string, or a number or whatever)

Comment: Show whole component as well as where it is used.

Comment: Clarification required. You need help with `createUserFuturesAssetsConstraints` method, but the method is never called from endpoint `/futures`.

Comment: Also, you're using `getPermittedFuturesAssets[traderId]` in the `/futures` endpoint but it is a function not an Object or Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would implore you to isolate logic in clear containers; for instance by creating repository modules or classes that are responsible for fetching data, service modules for calling the repository and executing business rules related to the authorization etc.
2. The endpoint `/futures` appears to imply that you want to return a list of futures (which I assume refers to a list of financial products). The middleware in your source code is defined as `checkAuthenticated`; however, authentication and authorization are two different things. Whereas authentication refers to the verification of whether a person is who he says he is, while authorization refers to the verification of necessary user rights to access the resource.
   Therefore I would suggest using different layers (read: chained middleware functions); i.e. separate authentication and authorization as separate layers, returning an adequate http status response code for each (isAuthenticated: 401 authentication, isAuthorized: 403 authorization for error codes).

3. Authorizations are usually stored in the database according to an agreed upon RBAC (role based access control). This allows roles to be assigned according to domain specific parameters, and can later on be managed dynamically by admins.
   The middleware you apply for verifying authorizations is therefore simple and based on the role the user was assigned.
4. In your source code you hint to certain constraints, which might imply you want to create a constraints table and link those constraints to a role.
   Without understanding the data model you're working with, it is difficult to assess, but with the information provided you should be able to come up with a model that works for you.

If there is any misunderstanding on the question, don't hesitate to comment.